# How do you center a div in Firefox and IE?

Tags: browser, html, overlay, center

I'm using the following code:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="black">
<center>
<div style="width:1080px;height:288px;">
<img src="declined.png" width="1080" height="288" alt="" style="z-index:0;position:absolute;" ondragstart="return false"/>
<img src="cover.png" width="1080" height="288" alt="Declined."" style="z-index:1;position:absolute;" ondragstart="return false" />
</div>
</center>
</html>
```

It works in Chrome but not in IE or Firefox. My goal with this is to overlay cover.png over declined.png so people cannot directly save the image, but instead save a transparent png. I prefer to do this without using external CSS. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Why `img` positions are absolute?

Comment: Without that the cover.png will not lay over declined.png.

Answer (score 2):

The standard method in css is to use `margin: 0 auto`, so:

```
<div style="width: 1080px; height: 288px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative">
   <img ... >
   <img ... >
</div>
```

Note the addition of `position: relative`. Without that, your images would position themselves absolutely relative to the `<body>` element. Also note that these sorts of overlays are trivial to bypass by anyone with the slightest knowledge of HTML and/or access to basic browser developer tools.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just being lazy by not copying the entire thing, since the important bit is the style you're setting on the `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

-Avoid using old tags such as  instead use CSS. 
-Use appropriate DOCTYPE (example below shows doctype for html5)
-Always close your tags, your code does not have closing tags for body.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" style="width:1080px;height:288px;">
        <img src="declined.png" width="1080" height="288" alt="" style="z-index:0;position:absolute;" ondragstart="return false"/>
        <img src="cover.png" width="1080" height="288" alt="Declined."" style="z-index:1;position:absolute;" ondragstart="return false" />
    </div><!-- end div main -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1080px;
   height:288px; 
}
```